# what does $Blah$ in JSP mean?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I am using Intellij to generate jsp, and I saw there is some token like

```
<title>$Title$</title>
```

My question is what does $TITLE$ mean here? Is this a variable?

How to set it?

Comment: Pretty sure that's an auto generated value intended for you to rewrite. Regarding your variable question - what's any JSP tutorial shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Intellij IDE generated the JSP and tool doesn't know what title need to be used for your JSP. So Intellij provided some temporary value.

After generating JSP, replace with required value (i.e JSP title)

**Example:**

```
<title>My First JSP</title>
```